# Modify custom option of product in cart

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, cart, magento-1.9.1

I have this code in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml for retrieving data.

```
$allProductOptions = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)>getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
    $productOptions = $allProductOptions['info_buyRequest'];
```

And in `$productOptions` I have custom option saved from product page: `$productOptions['my_option']`. How can I update that option?

Comment: Try `$allProductOptions = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptions();` instead of `$allProductOptions = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)>getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());`

Comment: but I need to be able to set them/update them. indeed that looks more practical.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Product custom Options :

```
$allProductOptions = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptions();
```

Update the custom options (Set your values like below) :

```
$option = array(
    'title' => 'Test Option',
    'type' => 'file',
    'is_require' => 1,
    'price' => 10,
    'price_type' => 'fixed',
    'sku' => 'testsku',
    'file_extension' => 'png,jpg',
    'image_size_x' => '100',
    'image_size_y' => '200'
```

);

```
$product = $_item->getProduct();

$product->getOptionInstance()->addOption($option);

$product->setHasOptions(true);
```

or

```
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance();
$optionInstance->addOption($option);
$optionInstance->setProduct($product);
$product->save();
```

You can update by these